# Can't cross-compile libstdc++ for AIX7.1

Tags: gcc, g++, cross-compiling, libstdc++

I am trying to cross-compile gcc 4.8.2 for Power8 AIX7.1. Successfully compiled binutils, gcc binaries and libgcc but can't compile libstdc++.

I get such error:

```
checking whether the /home/zakkurasov/Sources/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/zakkurasov/Sources/build-gcc/./gcc/ -B/opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/bin/ -B/opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/lib/ -isystem /opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/include -isystem /opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/sys-include  -maix64 linker (/home/zakkurasov/Sources/build-gcc/./gcc/collect-ld) supports shared libraries... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
Makefile:10072: recipe for target 'configure-target-libstdc++-v3' failed
make: *** [configure-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 1
```

Configuring:

```
CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 ../gcc-4.8.3/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-sysroot=$SYSROOT --disable-libgcj --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-nls --with-cloog=no --with-ppl=no --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-__cxa_atexit
```

Where:

```
$PREFIX=/opt/aix
$TARGET=powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0
$SYSROOT contains all libs and headers from AIX system
```

Also received such error:

```
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0-gcc... /home/zakkurasov/Sources/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/zakkurasov/Sources/build-gcc/./gcc/ -B/opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/bin/ -B/opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/lib/ -isystem /opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/include -isystem /opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/sys-include  -maix64
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/home/zakkurasov/Sources/build-gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/ppc64/libgomp':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU Binutils does not function correctly on AIX 6.1, AIX 7.1 nor AIX 7.2. It does not produce correct shared objects. It also passes some feature tests in GCC but does not implement the features correctly for AIX.

You can overcome the configure shared library test, but you will not be able to create a working GCC cross-compiler.

Any customers who need this functionality should express their requirements to their IBM sales representative.

Comment: Very interesting, because I can successfully compile C programs using libc, and it runs well on AIX.

Comment: And maybe any suggestions to make C++ cross-compiler working?

Comment: For very simple features, GNU Binutils functions. It's not completely broken. However, it does not produce valid shared objects for recent releases of AIX. It does not correctly support AIX DWARF debugging.

GNU Binutils is good enough for simple programs that link against existing libraries.  GCC and its runtime are not simple.

Comment: Cross-compiling -- literally compiling, creating assembly language files for AIX -- should work. One may be able to install the GCC runtime built on an AIX system or from pre-built packages combined with GNU Binutils and use that to cross-compile a C++ application that will run on AIX. That it different than building GCC as a cross-compiler using the normal GCC cross-tools methods.

Comment: So I can just take libs and includes from aix, and use it with my binaries? Or what?

Comment: You can copy the AIX includes and libraries into the sysroot. One also needs the GCC provided header files and the GCC "fix includes" header files. With all of that, you should be able to make more progress.